# API Platform - Don't have primary key, access by two fields non uniques

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have an entity "Product" with fields "CompanyCode" (integer, non unique) and "ProductCode" (string, non unique), I don't have primary key in this entity.

I want access:

- /companies/{companycode}/products
- /companies/{companycode}/products/{productcode}

I don't find documentation to make the identification by two fields.

Answer (score -2):

You can get your entity with the annotation @Entity or @ParamConverter [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression).  You can also write your own [paramconverter](https://stfalcon.com/en/blog/post/symfony2-custom-paramconverter).